# Expected attn_mask dtype to be bool or to match query dtype, but got attn_mask.dtype: float and query.dtype: c10::BFloat16 instead

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pytorch, torch, stable-diffusion

I want to install "Stable Diffusion" on a paperspace virtual machine (OS: Ubuntu)

I have customized the installation to use "xformers".

1. Creation of the ldm environment (via the "environment.yaml" file):

```
name: ldm
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.10.9
  - pip=23.0.1
  - numpy=1.23.1
```

2. installation of dependencies :

```
conda activate ldm
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
conda install xformers -c xformers
pip install transformers diffusers invisible-watermark
pip install omegaconf einops pytorch_lightning open_clip_torch
pip install -e .
```

Problems :
There seems to be a type problem in the file "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py"

Logs:

```
python scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "a professional photograph of an astronaut riding a horse" --ckpt model/768-v-ema.ckpt --config configs/stable-diffusion/v2-inference-v.yaml --H 768 --W 768
Global seed set to 42
Loading model from model/768-v-ema.ckpt
Global Step: 140000
LatentDiffusion: Running in v-prediction mode
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is None and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is 1024 and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is None and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is 1024 and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is None and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is 1024 and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is None and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is 1024 and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is None and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is 1024 and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is None and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is 1024 and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is None and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is 1024 and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is None and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is 1024 and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is None and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is 1024 and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is None and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 1280, context_dim is 1024 and using 20 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is None and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is 1024 and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is None and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is 1024 and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is None and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 640, context_dim is 1024 and using 10 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is None and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is 1024 and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is None and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is 1024 and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is None and using 5 heads.
Setting up MemoryEfficientCrossAttention. Query dim is 320, context_dim is 1024 and using 5 heads.
DiffusionWrapper has 865.91 M params.
making attention of type 'vanilla-xformers' with 512 in_channels
building MemoryEfficientAttnBlock with 512 in_channels...
Working with z of shape (1, 4, 32, 32) = 4096 dimensions.
making attention of type 'vanilla-xformers' with 512 in_channels
building MemoryEfficientAttnBlock with 512 in_channels...
Creating invisible watermark encoder (see https://github.com/ShieldMnt/invisible-watermark)...
Sampling:   0%|                                                                                                             | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s---------///////                                                                                                             | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
*********
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
*********
tensor([[[[0., -inf, -inf,  ..., -inf, -inf, -inf],
          [0., 0., -inf,  ..., -inf, -inf, -inf],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., -inf, -inf, -inf],
          ...,
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., -inf, -inf],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., -inf],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]]]])
*********
data:   0%|                                                                                                                 | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Sampling:   0%|                                                                                                             | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paperspace/latent-diffusion/stablediffusion/scripts/txt2img.py", line 388, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "/home/paperspace/latent-diffusion/stablediffusion/scripts/txt2img.py", line 342, in main
    uc = model.get_learned_conditioning(batch_size * [""])
  File "/home/paperspace/latent-diffusion/stablediffusion/ldm/models/diffusion/ddpm.py", line 665, in get_learned_conditioning
    c = self.cond_stage_model.encode(c)
  File "/home/paperspace/latent-diffusion/stablediffusion/ldm/modules/encoders/modules.py", line 193, in encode
    return self(text)
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paperspace/latent-diffusion/stablediffusion/ldm/modules/encoders/modules.py", line 170, in forward
    z = self.encode_with_transformer(tokens.to(self.device))
  File "/home/paperspace/latent-diffusion/stablediffusion/ldm/modules/encoders/modules.py", line 177, in encode_with_transformer
    x = self.text_transformer_forward(x, attn_mask=self.model.attn_mask)
  File "/home/paperspace/latent-diffusion/stablediffusion/ldm/modules/encoders/modules.py", line 189, in text_transformer_forward
    x = r(x, attn_mask=attn_mask)
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/open_clip/transformer.py", line 242, in forward
    x = q_x + self.ls_1(self.attention(q_x=self.ln_1(q_x), k_x=k_x, v_x=v_x, attn_mask=attn_mask))
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/open_clip/transformer.py", line 228, in attention
    return self.attn(
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py", line 1189, in forward
    attn_output, attn_output_weights = F.multi_head_attention_forward(
  File "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 5340, in multi_head_attention_forward
    attn_output = scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, attn_mask, dropout_p, is_causal)
RuntimeError: Expected attn_mask dtype to be bool or to match query dtype, but got attn_mask.dtype: float and  query.dtype: c10::BFloat16 instead.
```

modification of file "/home/paperspace/anaconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py":

```
        if attn_mask is not None:
            if attn_mask.size(0) == 1 and attn_mask.dim() == 3:
                attn_mask = attn_mask.unsqueeze(0)
                print("---------///////")
            else:
                attn_mask = attn_mask.view(bsz, num_heads, -1, src_len)
                print("+++++++////////")

        q = q.view(bsz, num_heads, tgt_len, head_dim)
        k = k.view(bsz, num_heads, src_len, head_dim)
        v = v.view(bsz, num_heads, src_len, head_dim)
        print("*********")
        print(type(attn_mask))
        print("*********")
        print(attn_mask)
        print("*********")
```

Comment: Try adding `--device cuda` at the end of your `python scripts/txt2img.py` command. Source: https://github.com/Stability-AI/stablediffusion/issues/203